# Does install4j support indeterminate progress bar (barber's pole or beach ball)?

Tags: java, install4j

Is there an install4j UI for an progress indicator without a set percentage (e.g., Barber's Pole or Beach ball)?

I have a long running process which varies from machine to machine.  I'm currently following the Microsoft protocol or resetting project bar to zero upon reaching 100 which is OK but not a nice to the user given it sets false expectations.

Is there standard UI for handling unknown progress that I can use, or would this be custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a "Set the progress bar" action and set its "Type of change" property to "Set indeterminate state".

With the API, you can call

```
context.getProgressInterface().setIndeterminateProgress(true);
```